# CSS overlay img alwasy on same place

Tags: css, position, geometry

I have some circles in CSS and i want to place a "sticker" over the circles. But i want that the sticker is alwasy on the same place on every circle how can i manage that?

See the red circle that is the sticker.

[image]

Now i have the CSS for the sticker as:

```
.icon {
    position : absolute;
    bottom : -5%;
    right : 30%;
}
```

But thats not working because every circle can be different in size. So the sticker is standing on every circle on a different place...

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qs1j2su9/)

Comment: paste your full code

Comment: Use `pixel` values instead of `percentage` values and ensure that it is nested within the circle which is positioned `relative`

Comment: @Bhargav see the JSfiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Use percentage values for the values that are not supposed to be static and change when the circle size changes.

```css
.big {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
}
.small {
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
}
.smallest {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}

.circleBig {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:black;
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.circleSmall {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:red;
  display: block;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 65%;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <div class="circleBig">
    <div class="circleSmall">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="small">
  <div class="circleBig">
    <div class="circleSmall">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="smallest">
  <div class="circleBig">
    <div class="circleSmall">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `<div class="icon">` a percentage of your outer container (with a slight offset to account for very small sizes, using calc) and position it bottom: 0, right: 0.

You might have to tweak the final values, but something like this should give you a very scalable solution as it will always adjust the offset based on a percentage of the parent container:

```
.circle-out .icon {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: calc(25px + 22%);
    height: calc(25px + 22%);
}
```

Here's a [modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sm3y3Lfs/). The advantage of this approach is that it's dynamic and doesn't require multiple declarations based on the size of your outer circle, so if you needed to create another 50 circle sizes in between (or even have a resizable circle), you'd still only need the one class.